# Multer's req.body works but req.files gives undefined

Tags: node.js, express, multer

I'm trying to submit a form , that consists some text and an image file to the server. Regarding multer, my understanding is that, multer creates a storage folder for our images `'my-uploads/'`  and we pass on the key from `formData.append('imageFile', imageFile)` to  `upload.single('imageFile')`. I tried giving paths like: `my-uploads/`, `/my-uploads`, `./my-uploads`, so far none of it is working.

Next, using Fetch, I have been able to send the text body to the server and it reaches in `[Object: null prototype]....`.(Not sure if it the right way of sending). The image files is not showing up the way expected too. Multer throws `undefined` when called `req.files`. Where is it going wrong with the code?

html:

```
   <form class="blogForm" method="post" encType="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" class="imageInput" name="file" multiple = "true"/>
    <div class="blogEntryDiv" contenteditable="true"></div>
    <input class= "blogSubmitButton" type="submit" value="Submit" >
  </form>
```

js

```
   document.querySelector('.blogForm').addEventListener('submit', (e) => {

      let formData = new FormData();
      let textContent = document.querySelector('.blogEntryDiv').innerText
      let imageFile = document.querySelector('.imageInput').files
      formData.append('textcontent', textContent);
      formData.append('imageFile', imageFile);
      
      fetch(`/someimage`, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData
          }).then(function (res){ 
            console.log(res);
          }).then(json => console.log(json))
          .catch(err => console.log(err));

   })
```

app.js:

```
 const multer  = require('multer');


 const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
       cb(null, 'my-uploads/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      const uniqueSuffix = Date.now() + '-' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1E9)
      cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + uniqueSuffix)
    }
  })

 const upload = multer({ storage: storage })



 app.post('/someimage', upload.single('imageFile'),  (req, resp) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    console.log(req.files)//gives undefined
 })
```

req.body gives:

```
  [Object: null prototype] {
    textcontent: '\n\nlorem lorem',
    imageFile: '[object FileList]' //gives a string
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`formData.append('imageFile', imageFile)` does not work, because `imageFile` is a file list, but you can only append single files. Use `formData.append('imageFile', imageFile[0])`.

Also, multer will write the single file into `req.file`, not into `req.files`.

Comment: Hi there, you were right. After adding imageFile[0], it started working. Also `req.files `and `req.file` both give same result. I was thinking that multer will automatically create a folder, but i was wrong. I had to create a folder called `my-uploads`. the image gets stored within it. Thank you.

Comment: Yea you were right the second time too. it is `req.file` not `req.files`.